# What to chose application/x-www-form-urlencoded / multipart/form-data for file size in GB?

Tags: http, post, http-headers, url-encoding

I am sending some video files (size could be even in GB) as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`over `HTTP POST`.

The following link [link](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/524c7e811e4abf9afe56) suggests that it would be better to transmit it over Multipart form data when we have non-alphanumeric content.

1. Which encoding would be better to transmit data of this kind?
2. Also how can I find the length of encoded data (data encoded with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)?
3. Will encoding the binary data consume much time?
4. In general, encoding skips the non-alphanumeric characters with some others. So, can we skip encoding for binary data (like video)? How can we skip it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x-www-form-urlencoded` treats the value of an entry in the *form data set* as a sequence of bytes (octets).
Of the possible 256 values, only 66 are left as it or still encoded as a single byte value, the others are replaced by the hexadecimal representation of the value of their code-point. 
This usually takes three to five bytes depending on the encoding.
So in average (256-66)/256 or 74% of the file will be encoded to take three-to-five as much space as originally. 
This encoding however has no header nor significant overhead.

`multipart/form-data` instead works by dividing the data into parts and then finding a string of any length that doesn't occur in said part.
Such string is called the *boundary* and it is used to delimit the end of the part, that is transmitted as a stream of octects.
So the file is mostly send as it, with negligible size overhead for big enough data.

The draw back is that the user-agent need to find a suitable boundary, however given a string of length *k* there is only a probability of 2<sup>-8k</sup> of finding that string in a uniformly generated binary file.
So the user-agent can simply generate a random string and do a quick search and exploit the network transmission time to hide the latency of the search.

---

1. You should use `multipart/form-data`.
2. This depends on the platform you are using, in general if you cannot access the request body you have to re-perform the encoding your self.
3. For `multipart/form-data` encoding there is a little, usually negligible (compared to the transmission time) overhead.

Comment: In a `multipart/form-data` it won't.